# Bluetooth devices not reconnecting after sleep

Tags: bluetooth

Ever since I installed Ubuntu, Bluetooth devices are not reconnected after sleeping. Windows, for instance, does that. There are a couple posts about this, but they are all old.

Therefore, I would like to know whether:
a) this is the normal behavior or a bug
b) there is any work around

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Thank you very much!